# Response.Redirect and Server.Transfer

Tags: asp.net, redirect, server.transfer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Server.Transfer Vs. Response.Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224569/server-transfer-vs-response-redirect)

What are the differences between Response.Redirect and Server.Transfer in ASP.NET?

In what situations would one want to use one instead of the other?