# HTTPModule BeginRequest should us Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer

Tags: asp.net, httpmodule, url-rewriting

We have a URLRewriting module that is using a Response.Redirect in the BeginRequest event method to change the destination page.

- Would it be better to use Server.Transfer or Server.TransferRequest instead of Response.Redirect?
- There are other HTTP Modules in the solution, will I bypass any of the other modules by using Server.Transfer or will the server begin as though it is a new request, just saving the round trip to the browser?
- Will the client notice any differences and will the server treat the request differently in anyway?

The following questions cover the differences between redirect and transfer but not within an HTTP Module;

- [Server.Transfer Vs. Response.Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224569/server-transfer-vs-response-redirect)
- [Response.Redirect and Server.Transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521527/response-redirect-vs-server-transfer)

**EDIT:** [HttpContext.RewritePath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.rewritepath.aspx) is also used in the module so it seems we have three techniques to move the initial Request from the original path; Redirect, Transfer, RewritePath which respectively; go back to browser, back to start of HTTP pipeline and continue processing on new path.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's the best explanation of Redirect vs Transfer vs RewritePath; http://www.developerfusion.com/article/4643/implementing-http-handlers-in-aspnet/4/

To summarise; Redirect requires roundtrip to browser, Transfer ensures the original Request object remains not the new request but has problems with Post-backs, Rewrite loses the orginal Request object but is the best for performance.