# What event should I use in the IHttpModule to disable website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpmodule

I want to disable a website programatically for licensing reasons, and I want to do it in a httpmodule.

Ive tried to redirect the context :

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.Response.Redirect("http://vls.pete.videolibraryserver.com");
}
```

But I get the error:

```
Response is not available in this context.
```

Anybody know how I can effectively disable the website and preferably send them to a custom page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `BeginRequest` event for redirection, like following:

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{
    context.BeginRequest += new EventHandler(context_BeginRequest);
}

void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
    application.Context.Response.Redirect("http://vls.pete.videolibraryserver.com");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Server.Transfer` as this will save a round trip provided the custom page is on the same machine; [HTTPModule BeginRequest should us Response.Redirect or Server.Transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757336/httpmodule-beginrequest-should-us-response-redirect-or-server-transfer) (this is my own question I answered - not trying to be self promoting)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a better way to close the site would be to programmatically write out an **App_Offline.htm** file to the root of the website. To quote from [Scott Guthrie's blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/04/09/442332.aspx):

> "The way app_offline.htm works is that
>   you place this file in the root of the
>   application.  When ASP.NET sees it, it
>   will shut-down the app-domain for the
>   application (and not restart it for
>   requests) and instead send back the
>   contents of the app_offline.htm file
>   in response to all new dynamic
>   requests for the application.  When
>   you are done updating the site, just
>   delete the file and it will come back
>   online."

Answer (score 0):

```
public void Init(HttpApplication context)
{

    context.Response.Write("for licence visit this <a href=\"http://vls.pete.videolibraryserver.com\">link</a>");
    context.Response.End();

}
```

you can use this code