# How to auto-redirect URLs by patterns in ASP.NET / IIS 6?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis-6, global-asax

I thought it should be a simple straight-forward matter but after struggling with it for too much time I'm gonna have to seek for help.

What I need is to redirect all requests for my web application that match the following pattern - "`^(http://[^/]+/blogs/[^/.]+)/?$`"  to the path of "`$1/Default.aspx`".

(Using English rather than Regex: `http://myapp/blogs/randomdirthatdoesntexist` -> `http://myapp/blogs/randomdirthatdoesntexist/default.aspx`)

The sub-directories in "blogs" do not physically exist, instead a 3rd party product deals with the requests to randomdir/Default.aspx", but when you go to "randomdir/" you get 404 not found, which is what I'm trying to fix.

I tried to use `global.asax` and also `HttpHandler`, but I couldn't get either of them to fire up on the requests to those 404 paths.

So, in short, what should I do to redirect paths of non-existing directories?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished something similar to this by setting the Error Page for 404s in IIS to a page you create.  This page is able to access the page which is being requested, and perform some additional logic.  So the 404 for randomdirthatdoesntexist/ still happens, but the 404 handler notices this and redirects to randomdirthatdoesntexist/default.aspx.

I dug out my old code and tweaked it a little to do what you need in an over-simplified fashion, but I don't have IIS6 anywhere to test:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String sQueryString = Request.RawUrl.Substring(Request.FilePath.Length);
    Regex rx = new Regex(@"^\?(?<errorcode>\d+);(?<args>.*)$", RegexOptions.ExplicitCapture | RegexOptions.Compiled);
    Match m = rx.Match(sQueryString);


    if (m.Success)
    {
        if (m.Groups["errorcode"].Value == "404")
        {
            String sArgs = m.Groups["args"].Value;
            Uri requestedUri = new Uri(sArgs);

            // You can now check the value of uri and perform redirection...
            if (requestedUri.ToString().EndsWith("/"))
            {
                Response.Redirect(requestedUri + "Default.aspx")
            }
        }
    }
    Response.StatusCode = 404;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up referring the 404 and 403 error pages in IIS to my HttpHandler, works like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Custom HttpModule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719858%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), or Http Handler, which sits in early enough in the Http Request pipeline to direct your requests appropriately before any possible 404 response is determined.

See my own SO Q&A; [Server.Transfer or Server.RewritePath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757336/httpmodule-beginrequest-should-us-response-redirect-or-server-transfer) for more details.

Comment: I didn't understand from this answer how am I supposed to put my HttpHandler earlier in the pipeline.

Comment: @yellowblood You add the HttpModule in the web.config and it can have custom code in Application_BeginRequest to alter the destination on the server of the HttpRequest using Server.Transfer. This is how URL rewriting often works. There is also Application_EndRequest which can modify the response just prior to it going back to the client. This article might give you a better idea; http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011404-1.aspx

Comment: Thanks for clearing that up, if I will ever face this issue again this seems like a better way of doing it.