# How do you correctly handle 404 errors in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, response

In the web.config you can add this code to handle 404 errors:

```
<customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="ErrorPage.aspx">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="/Site-Map"/>
</customErrors>
```

And this works well as you can see by this URL http://www.fundraising.com.au/thisisnotapage

However, according to this website http://gsitecrawler.com/tools/Server-Status.aspx the response code for this non-existent page is 200, not a 404.

Whilst this page http://www.nuenergy.com.au/thisisnotapage does show a 404 at http://gsitecrawler.com/tools/Server-Status.aspx and redirects to another page.

How do you achieve the later in ASP.NET?
I need the response to be a 404 and for another page to show up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [custom errors section employs the HttpHandler](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/CustomErrorPages) to intercept the fact you don't have a page and then [redirects the response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521527/response-redirect-vs-server-transfer) so that the server returns `Site-Map` instead which is an available resource so the 200 status is correct since its as though the request was for `Site-Map` in the first place.

You ultimately want to serve two versions of `Site-Map`, one when it is the actual request (200) but also one when it is the custom error response (404). I would create another version of the `Site-Map` page, `OnError-Site-Map`, extending the pages class to inherit it's features but then [overriding the http response code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.statuscode.aspx) so that it delivers the 404 status you want but for that extended version only. You then put that in the custom errors section in the web.config instead.

Answer (score 1):

For your page to return a 404 status, add the following code to your Page_Load event:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load1(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    Response.Status = "404 Not Found"

End Sub
```