# Server.Transfer Method

Tags: .net, asp.net, server.transfer

When should I use `Server.Transfer()` method?

What is the advantage of using this method?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Response.Redirect vs. Server.Transfer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521527/response-redirect-vs-server-transfer)

Answer (score 0):

You could use `Server.Transfer` to execute some other server side page without changing the address on the client and without an additional redirect which is what `Response.Redirect` does.

Answer (score 0):

`Server.Transfer` allows you to redirect a request on the **server-side** to another resource on that server. This differs from `Response.Redirect` which redirects the **client** to another resource.

This means that processing of the requested resource is redirected to another existing resource. For example, you could have the request:

```
http://mydomain.com/users/100032
```

be handled by another resource on the server:

```
http://mydomain.com/users/100032/details
```

`Server.Transfer` will have the effect of **both** URLs returning the same response.

This differs from `Response.Redirect`, which has the effect of telling the client's browser "the resource you are requesting is at a different URL". In this case, the client's browser will make a new request to the URL and the client will see the URL change in their address bar to reflect this.