# How can we call pages

Tags: asp.net, redirect

in asp.net (with VB) how can we redirect (in code Behind) our page to another one?

Comment: http://www.bing.com/search?q=asp.net+redirect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/521527/response-redirect-vs-server-transfer :)

Answer (score 1):

Response.Redirect("/WhateverUrl.aspx")

Answer (score 1):

Using [Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: and if i make session variable.. i can use in the code behind of the WAthever page?

Answer (score 0):

```
Response.Redirect("newUrl.html")
```

To transfer the page w/o changing the browser's URL:

```
Server.Transfer("newUrl.html")
```

Comment: But be careful with Server.Transfer as it will require Classic Pipeline mode instead of Integrated, that is default for IIS 6 and 7