# Difference between response.redirect and server.transfer

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Response.Redirect vs. Server.Transfer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521527/response-redirect-vs-server-transfer)
>   [Server.Transfer Vs. Response.Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224569/server-transfer-vs-response-redirect)

What is the difference between response.redirect and server.transfer?
Only one difference i know is: In response.redirect the browser url changes to targeted page as well as in server.transfer the url remains same!
any other difference?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

**Response.Redirect should be used when:**

- we want to redirect the request to some plain HTML pages on our
  server or to some other web server
- we don't care about causing additional roundtrips to the server on
       each request
- we do not need to preserve Query String and Form Variables from the
      original request
- we want our users to be able to see the new redirected URL where he
      is redirected in his browser (and be able to bookmark it if its
      necessary)

**Server.Transfer should be used when:**

- we want to transfer current page request to another .aspx page on the same server
- we want to preserve server resources and avoid the       unnecessary
  roundtrips to the server
- we want to preserve Query String    and Form Variables (optionally)
- we don't need to show the real URL where we redirected the request in
  the users Web   Browser

Comment: transfer current page request to another .aspx page on the same server. y can't it redirect to the another server? Can u explain this in detail.

Answer (score 13):

`Response.Redirect()` sends a redirection header to the client, and the client itself requests the new page.

`Server.Transfer()` only stops rendering the current page and starts rendering another one. The client is none the wiser.

That's why `Server.Transfer()` cannot be used to redirect to pages served by another server.

Comment: So we not use querry string or some thing else which is client specific in server.transfer?

Comment: @Shoaib, absolutely. The client is not involved in `Server.Transfer()` in any way, and doesn't know it took place. That's why the URL in the browser doesn't change.

Answer (score 2):

Server.Transfer is more efficient because with Response.Redirect you tell the browser to make another request (another network roundtrip) whil Server.Transfer is "server-internal"...

Answer (score 0):

The Form data is transferred on Server.Transfer, but not on Response.Redirect, one other difference. 
Also, if not mistaken, Server.Transfer works on the same server, not cross-server pages.