# my asp:LinkButton does not perform its OnClick action when I add a second button

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having to have 2 buttons to correctly behave inside a div.

If I set a single button redirecting to a code behing method, it works fine:

```
<div class="divBtNavCommande">
     <asp:LinkButton ID="bt_1" runat="server" OnClick="myAction">
      My text 1
     </asp:LinkButton>                  
</div>
```

If I add a second buttons redirecting to a link, the redirection works fine but the first button nolonger performs the code behind action:

```
 <div class="divBtNavCommande">
     <asp:LinkButton ID="bt_1" runat="server" OnClick="myAction">
       My text 1
     </asp:LinkButton>

     <asp:LinkButton ID="bt_2" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/MyPage.aspx">
       My text 2
     </asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

And if I remove the                        `PostBackUrl="~/myPage.aspx"`part, the first button works again.

What is wrong?

Comment: Is it a typo or have you forgot to add a `OnClick` method on the second linkbutton?

Comment: You are missing `>` in the second button tag `<asp:LinkButton ID="bt_2" runat="server">`

Comment: @ElectricRouge : was a typo in my question, I updated the post.

Comment: @Hypnobrew : the second button performs a 
  PostBackUrl="~/MyPage.aspx"

Comment: So bt_2 should not perform any action in the code behind?

Comment: For me you code seems to be correct, Try clean and rebuld the solution

Comment: @ Hypnobrew  : yep.
Button1 should perform a code behind action.
Button 2 should perform a redirect.

Comment: Why do you use a `LinkButton` for nr2 and not a regular `<a href` if it is only for navigation? Can you show some code behind. and is button1 and 2 in the mypage.aspx file?

Comment: Ok, I see now after you fixed the code. Maybe you can try to set the `PostBackUrl` on bt_1 explicit?

Comment: @ JP Hellemons : I used a LinkButton as well  so I could keep the same class / design for both buttons

Comment: @ JaydipJ : rebuilding did not help.

Comment: @A.D. and are both buttons on `MyPage.aspx`? because a "form" submit is a postback, so you do not need the `PostBackUrl` attribute if they are on the `MyPage.aspx` webform.

Comment: @JP Hellemons : no these 2 buttons are on a different page than MyPage.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

YourPage.aspx:

```
<div class="divBtNavCommande">
 <asp:LinkButton ID="bt_1" runat="server" OnClick="myAction">
   My text 1
 </asp:LinkButton>

 <asp:LinkButton ID="bt_2" runat="server" OnClick="bt_2_OnClick">
   My text 2
 </asp:LinkButton>
</div>
```

YourPage.aspx.cs:

```
protected void bt_2_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("MyPage.aspx");
}
```

Because you said that it was for nagivation purposes only. Otherwise use `Server.Transer();` more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6778952/169714

Comment: That would work, this is what I had in mind. Thanks.

Do you know why the solution that I posted does not work although both buttons operate correctly separately if I add only one of the 2 buttons (any of the 2), but do not work if the 2 buttons are present?

Comment: Perhaps your `Page_Load` show some more code behind ;) As said here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.postbackurl(v=vs.110).aspx perhaps the server-side validation? I need more context I think.