# Thread was being aborted

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, server.transfer

I am using **Server.Transfer**. Everything works fine, but exception log shows following exception.

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.Thread.AbortInternal()
   at System.Threading.Thread.Abort(Object stateInfo)
   at System.Web.HttpResponse.End()
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path, Boolean preserveForm)
   at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Transfer(String path)
```

Any idea to avoid above exception.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This exception is throw by the call to `Server.Transfer` in order to halt the execution of the current method - exactly the same thing gets thrown if you do `Response.Redirect`.

The two choices you have are:

- Catch and rethrow the
  ThreadAbortException / reperform the
  `Server.Transfer`
- Make sure that you
  only do `Server.Transfer` in places
  where it wont be caught (recommended)

**EDIT:** Scratch that, http://support.microsoft.com/kb/312629 has a couple of other suggestions to try, but I still recommend #2 above.

Answer (score 11):

Another way to solve this, is to catch the generated error and to not rethrow it:

```
        catch (ThreadAbortException)
        { 
        }
```

Comment: empty catches are ***bad***

Comment: @Rob, usually, but not always.

Answer (score 8):

Caling Server.Transfer will call Response.End which always throws a ThreadAbortException. This is a "special" exception because while it can be caught in a catch block, it will always be re thrown at the end of the catch block. I would have your error logging ignore ThreadAbortExceptions.

Comment: It make sense to me that Server.Transfer will call Response.End implicitly.

What do you mean by error logging ignore threadAbortException.

Comment: If you are logging exceptions to a persistable logging system, I would filter out ThreadAbortExceptions or have your reports that query this loging system filter them out.

Comment: It make sense that this exception is not serious one, therefore I can ignore it by filtering out..
thank you.

Answer (score 8):

This problem occurs in the `Response.Redirect` and `Server.Transfer` methods because both methods call `Response.End` internally.

Solution for this Problem is as follows.

For `Server.Transfer`, use the `Server.Execute` method instead.

Answer (score 1):

Replacing Response.End() by the following helped fix the problem.

Response.Flush();
Response.Close();

Refer [Can we use Response.Flush () instead of Response.End()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10829168/can-we-use-response-flush-instead-of-response-end)

Answer (score 1):

Replace `Response.End()` With `HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();`