# Response.redirect raises "Thread was being aborted"

Tags: vb.net, iis

I've a VB.NET code called when I need to delete an object from DB. On Page_load I check if it's not post back (to prevent a manual refresh) and, after the deletion of the object I redirect to the caller page using Response.redirect. At this point my code raise an

> exception:EXCEPTION OCCURS In
>   File_delete.aspx.vb Line Number: 34
>   Error Message: Thread was being
>   aborted.

and, on Event Viewer I can see that aspnet_wp.exe crashes:

> aspnet_wp.exe  (PID: 1532) stopped
>   unexpectedly.
>
> For more information, see Help and
>   Support Center at
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.

It's not clear why this happens only here because I use the response.redirect also to view the file and not only to delete it.

Comment: Close duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433448/thread-was-being-aborted

Answer (score 155, accepted):

By default, `Response.Redirect()` aborts the current thread.  Naturally, this throws a `ThreadAbortException`.  It can be prevented by passing a `false` to `Response.Redirect()`, which won't abort the current thread.

```
Response.Redirect(url,false)
```

Be aware of what that means, however.  If the thread is not aborted, the code following the `Response.Redirect()` will continue to execute.  Control your logic flow accordingly.  (This is often done with `return` statements and other flow control directives following a redirect.)

```
Response.Redirect(url,false) 
Return
```

Comment: I got an exception because my method there is async keyword

Answer (score 24):

`Response.Redirect` will always throw a `ThreadAbortException`, according to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx) if you don't give a `false` boolean value to `endResponse` input parameter `HttpRequest.Redirect(string, bool)`.

Just give `false` to `endResponse` parameter.

Comment: This is the recommended approach, you just need to be careful using this as code after the Response.Redirect will be executed.

Comment: After calling Response.Redirect(url, false) call   HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
to terminate without an exception.

Comment: But the Page lifecycle continues, Postback events are handled, and html is sent to the client. See http://www.c6software.com/CodeSolutions/dotnet/ThreadAbortException.aspx

Comment: @StanleyH yes, After calling Response.Redirect(url, false), the following code in current page will be run, this is not my purpose. how to resolve it.

Comment: @StanleyH No, it doesn't, the request continues with it's page life cycle.

Answer (score 6):

The list of options for solving this issue laid out here worked for me (I used #2):
https://gist.github.com/cemerson/9dea993044a4e7fdca0e

Answer (score 0):

`Response.Redirect` throws an exception by design. It is OK.

Comment: Why would it throw an exception ? I don't get the logic behind it.

Answer (score 0):

This could happens when you are making asynchronous calls.
Use Response.Redirect(string url, false) where string url is the redirect url.