# FIX connection getting stopped

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7.5, fix-protocol, quickfixn

I am running my application in IIS and after some time i got this in event logs and the application stopped connecting with ECN. I tried to disable recycling but still no success.
Can you please point me any solution

```
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOneNative(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, UInt32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, Int64 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean hasThreadAffinity, Boolean exitContext)
   at System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, Boolean exitContext)
   at QuickFix.SocketInitiatorThread.ReadSome(Byte[] buffer, Int32 timeoutMilliseconds)
   at QuickFix.SocketInitiatorThread.Read()
```

Comment: Use this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1433448/thread-was-being-aborted

Comment: A lot of servers will automatically disconnect an idle connection.  Adding a Keep Alive to the client will send periodically an empty message so channel is not idle and server will not close the connection.

Comment: but this is quickfixn library so i can't handle that exception myself

Comment: Do you have HeartBtInt=<nonzero> in your config?

Comment: yes it's 30 second