# How do i load or reload the same page on form post

Tags: asp.net, browser

I notice on some sites i can login wrong which brings me to a login page. log in incorrectly again which brings me to a wrong password page (where i can log in) and if i login wrong again i dont increase my page history count. It takes exactly 2 backs no matter how many times i get it wrong and i dont see any pages in my forward history

How do i do that? ASP.NET

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont. As long as the login url stays the same there wont be another page added to the history. There may be parameters after the ? that changes the url or possibly POST data.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this:

[Server.Transfer Vs. Response.Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224569/server-transfer-vs-response-redirect)

Basically, if you want to do it without the user (browser) knowing about it, you use Server.Transfer; otherwise you do a Response.Redirect.

Answer (score 0):

Also note, although not in server side code, there is a possibility the site uses Javascript like [location.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location) - this way the history does not change.