# Incorrect Url displaying after Response.Redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net

When I use

> Server.Transfer("PageName.aspx");

I am transferred to the correct page, but the url is the url of the first page.

In other words, say **page1.aspx** Server.Transfers to **page2.aspx**.

**page2.aspx** is rendered,  but the url reads **page1.aspx**.

The problem was I need to pass parameters to page2 in the url, and the params were not getting through.

I got around it by using

> Response.Redirect("PageName.aspx?parm=val");

I had been using Server.Transfer because I was under the impression it was more efficient.

What are the other differences? Are there any other reasons for using one rather than the other?

So far I have:

Use Response.Redirect

1. if you want to pass parms
2. if you want to transfer to a site on another server

Use Server.Transfer for

1. the efficiency of saving one server roundtrip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, Server.Transfer is more efficient because it eliminates a round-trip between the server and the browser.  Response.Redirect sends a redirect response back to the browser forcing the browser to send a new request back to the server with the redirected URL. Response.Redirect allows the browser to know what the redirected URL was and display it in the address box.  In the case of Server.Transfer, the browser has no clue that the response came from a different page.

Answer (score 5):

Well, there are certainly more detailed and probably more correct answers than this, but ...

Server.Transfer:

> **Browser:** Hey server, I want pageOne.aspx!
>
> **Server:** Suuuuure, here you go (sneaky laugh). *(returns pageTwo.aspx)*

Response.Redirect:

> **Browser:** Hey server, I want pageOne.aspx!
>
> **Server:** Actually, you want pageTwo.aspx.
>
> **Browser:** Oh, ... okay. Can I please have pageTwo.aspx?
>
> **Server:** Yup. *(returns pageTwo.aspx)*

Answer (score 2):

[`Server.Transfer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525800(VS.90).aspx) maintains the original URL in the browser and yes it is **more efficient** as it skips a round-trip but hence it should be only used for pages on the server.

Check [Server.Transfer vs Response.Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224569/server-transfer-vs-response-redirect) for better use of them.

Answer (score 0):

Server.Transfer is supposed to keep the URL in the address bar the same; that's the defined behavior. The way you are doing it with Response.Redirect is the correct way if you want to change the URL.