# server.transfer in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

When i write `server.transfer("defaul2.aspx");`
  in url `default2.aspx` is not displaying instead of it is showing `defaul.aspx` page.
 when i write `response.redirect("default2.aspx");`

in url `default2.aspx` page is showing what is there any different.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server.Transfer Vs. Response.Redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224569/server-transfer-vs-response-redirect)

Comment: It's not exact duplicate but answers this question as well. Hence I voted to close as well.

Comment: You also misspelled "defaul2.aspx" (missing "t") in your Server.Transfer call.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because [Server.Transfer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k58xk7.aspx) and [Response.Redirect()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4.aspx) don't work the same way.

`Server.Transfer()` doesn't end the current request, it only instructs ASP.NET to stop rendering the current page and start rendering the new page instead. The client is none the wiser, from its point of view the server is still responding to the initial request, so the URL displayed in the address bar does not change.

`Response.Redirect()` ends the current request and sends a [302](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) response code to the client. The client then issues *another* HTTP request to the redirected URL and processes the response. Since the client knows that the URL has changed, it displays the redirected URL in its address bar.

Answer (score 2):

**Response.Redirect method:**
it helps in navigating to another page from code. This is like clicking a hyperlink.To navigate from one page to another using  button click or linkbutton control or from server side code use Response Object's Redirect method.
using Response.rediect() method you can not get information from source page on target page.
its source code is like
VB.Net Code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal Sender as System.Object, ByVal e as System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Display target page.
    Response.Redirect("Target.aspx")
End Sub
```

C# Code

```
private void Button1_Click(Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
        //Display Target Page.
        Response.Redirect("Target.aspx");
}
```

**Using Server.Execute Method**
use Server.Execute Method to process a Target web form without leaving the Source page. This technique let you embed the result from a target page to a region on Source page. Like Server.Transfer, It also required EnableViewStateMac attribute to page directive set to false.
Suppose I have to pages one is Calculate.aspx having two textboxes and a button control. On button Click event. I performed Server.Execute to Result.aspx another aspx page.
Source Code:

```
 protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Execute("Result.aspx");
}
```

write below code in Result.aspx pageload event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    NameValueCollection colform = new NameValueCollection();
    colform = Request.Form;
    Response.Write("<h2>Additon Result:</h2>" + (Convert.ToInt32(colform["TextBox1"]) + Convert.ToInt32(colform["TextBox2"])));
}
```

Comment: Where is the `Server` object declared?