# Call javascript function from Global.asax without redirect

Tags: javascript, asp.net

When in my application occurs an exception (unhandled), i want to stay on the same web page and show an alert. Is it possible?
Example: in page X is raised an uncaught exception, the control flow reaches the global.asax where it is handled by the Application_Error method. I don't want the global.asax to performe a Response.Redirect but I want to remain in page X and show a javascript alert.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to do Response.Redirect, try Server.Transfer.
[Server.Transfer Vs. Response.Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224569/server-transfer-vs-response-redirect)