# Server.Transfer to a page

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore6, server.transfer

I am using Sitecore and I have to show the first page in a collection of pages. Here is my code so far:

```
private Item currItem = Sitecore.Context.Item;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (currItem.HasChildren || currItem.TemplateID == new Sitecore.Data.ID("45D58815-A301-4393-9BA0-30A00C9BB993"))
            {
                var getFirstChild = (from Item item in currItem.GetChildren()
                                     select item).First();
                if (getFirstChild.TemplateID == new Sitecore.Data.ID("45D58815-A301-4393-9BA0-30A00C9BB993") && getFirstChild != null)
                {
                    //Server.Transfer(getFirstChild.Paths.Path);
                }

                else
                {
                    //Load Generic Page!
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Load Generic Page!!!
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524309%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) or Server.Transfer. I would recommend Response.Redirect if you can:

[Server.Transfer Vs. Response.Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224569/server-transfer-vs-response-redirect)

EDIT:

OK you can do this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (currItem.HasChildren || currItem.TemplateID == new Sitecore.Data.ID("45D58815-A301-4393-9BA0-30A00C9BB993"))
            {
                var getFirstChild = (from Item item in currItem.GetChildren()
                                     select item).First();
                if (getFirstChild.TemplateID == new Sitecore.Data.ID("45D58815-A301-4393-9BA0-30A00C9BB993") && getFirstChild != null)
                {
                    Response.Redirect(getFirstChild.Paths.Path);
                }

                else
                {
                    //Load Generic Page!
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Load Generic Page!!!
            }
        }
    }
```

`Response` is a property of the `Page` so you can use it to redirect.

Comment: Tried it, didnt work. Can you show me the code? Thanks!

Comment: OK, can you post all of the code from the method you are using the above code please? Will see if I can help further when I see your code. I need to know if your code is in a Page_Load() or something like that.

Comment: Please see my edit. I have tabs in my page where each tab is itself is another.aspx page. When I am loading the home, then I am getting the first tab and I need to route my page to that.