# setting url to specified string value

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to specify the Url value Programatically and then to navigate to the page accordingly?

```
string url = http://localhost:4039/LRVisuals/Default.aspx;
Url.AbsolutePath = url;
```

Comment: You probably search for the Response.Redirect()

Comment: [http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307903](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307903)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Response.Redirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt.aspx) or [`Server.Transfer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y4k58xk7.aspx) to navigate to a page.

```
Response.Redirect(url);
```

You'll find differences between both [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224569/server-transfer-vs-response-redirect). With `Server.Transfer` `Page.PreviousPage` is not null and you're able to access controls or ViewState of it.