# Application_Error

Tags: c#, error-handling

I recently discovered that the IIS worker process in production was crashing 2-3 times per week. I noticed in the exception logs that the its because of an UnhandledException. I investigated and found that the Global.asax had no Server.Transfer call.

I then did some googling and it appears that it's better to use Response.Redirect. Is this true, I keep on getting mixed comments on this...

```
    void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
        if (null != Context && null != Context.AllErrors)
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Context.AllErrors.Length);

        //bool isUnexpectedException = true;
        HttpContext context = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;

        Exception ex = context.Server.GetLastError();
        if (ex.InnerException != null)
            ex = ex.InnerException;

        LogManager.ExceptionHandler(ex);

        Server.Transfer("GeneralError.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: "Is this true, I keep on getting mixed comments on this" What comments? Does using `Response.Redirect()` make the application work as you want it to work? And do you even have a choice if the other call isn't available in `Global.asax` hooks?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Server.Transfer Vs. Response.Redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/224569/server-transfer-vs-response-redirect)

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "global.asax had no server.transfer call".  You can certainly do a server.transfer from a global.asax file.  So, I'm failing to see the actual question here.  Use either `Server.Transfer` or `Request.Redirect` depending on what your goals are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on if you would want your user to see the "redirection".  Personally I would use Response.Redirect for this case.

Check out this answer on the difference between the two:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/224577/1260077