# Masking URLs in IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, url-rewriting, web-config, url-routing

I have a web site with a content management system. I want to redirect a URL say http://www.example.com/somefolder/somepage/ to different subdomain http://my.example.com

This can be easily achieved using URL alias. But I want to mask the rewritten URL, means in the browser address bar I want to display my.example.com (instead of http://www.example.com/somefolder/somepage/).

Is this something I can do in IIS?

Thanks

Comment: The URL `http://my.example.com` will have a single page or will it contain a website? E.g. there will be a URL like `http://my.example.com/somepage`? And if yes, what will the actual URL be?

Comment: http://my.example.com will be just a single page.

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic example of a reverse proxy - you can do this within iis - see this article 
http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/creating-a-reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-for-iis

Comment: I cant use reverse proxy for this

Comment: Its a shame you cannot use a reverse proxy - perhaps you could just use the url rewrite functionality within iis as discussed in my above link.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your requirements, but you could use `Server.Transfer(`) instead `redirect`.

It has some limitations; there is an explanation in this question:
[Server.Transfer Vs. Response.Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224569/server-transfer-vs-response-redirect)

Limits include:

Response.redirect() can be used to redirect user to any page which is not part of the application but server.transfer() can only be used to redirect user within the application. I am not so comfortable with the use of subdomains in one application so I cannot tell you directly if a subdomain can be in the same application or not.

Comment: My question is not about on click.

Comment: Does not matter, you can do it anywhere