# How can I pass the url of a selected image which is included in a listview from one aspx page to another?

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I am working on my class project where I created an image gallery  using listview. 
**The Designing is below:**

```
<asp:ListView ID="lvPresent" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <td>
            <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">

                <asp:Image ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("url")%>' Height="200px" Width="250px" />

            </asp:HyperLink>
        </td>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:ListView>
```

How can I send the url of the selected image from one .aspx page to another anothe ?

Comment: you can use session state to transfer data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To send URL to another page you can use `QueryString`.
Modify your `HyperLink` and add `NavigateUrl`

```
NavigateUrl='<%#"yourNextPageName.aspx?imgURL="+ Eval("url")%>'
```

just replace you code:-

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">

  <asp:Image ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("url")%>' Height="200px" Width="250px" />

</asp:HyperLink>
```

with

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl='<%#"yourNextPageName.aspx?imgURL="+ Eval("url")%>'>

  <asp:Image ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("url")%>' Height="200px" Width="250px" />

</asp:HyperLink>
```

Answer (score -1):

Add image URL as query string ,
`NavigateUrl ='yourNextPageName.aspx?imgURL=<%# Eval("url")%>'` 
 in `HyperLink`

```
   <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl ='yourNextPageName.aspx?imgURL=<%# Eval("url")%>' >

            <asp:Image ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%#Eval("url")%>' Height="200px" Width="250px" />

        </asp:HyperLink>
```

In destination page , get your image url as `string _imgURL =Request.QueryString["imgURL"];`

Comment: Is there any problem ?

Comment: yes, check your code before suggesting any solution.