# How do you properly redirect in IIS to subdirectory?

Tags: windows, http, iis

I have an IIS site that is under the 'Default Web Site'. I need my www.blahblahblah.com to go to www.blahblahblah.com/site

I have tried HTTP Redirect in the IIS console but it ends up redirecting too many times and not working. What is the proper way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try set `/site$S$Q`. Note: `$S$Q` is to save everything goes after `/site`, e.g. query string. Also, if you're using IIS 7+, you might need to use `$V$Q`.

Answer (score 0):

in your default page in www.blahblahblah.com do a server.transfer or a response.redirect to www.blahblahblah.com/site.  Your choice which method to use.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224569/server-transfer-vs-response-redirect) for a community discussion on it.