# response redirect conflict with image inserting

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I'm a beginner in C# and I have a problem with image uploading.
Everything in my code inserting in my database except for the files that I uploaded, I didn't know why it doesn't save it in the database, it only saved when I remove the `Response.Redirect("Personalinformation.aspx")` but I can't remove this response redirect because I need it.

protected void Button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

```
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString);
    con.Open();
    if (con.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        if (TextBox11.Text != "" && TextBox8.Text != "" && TextBox9.Text != "" )
        {
            if (FileUpload1.PostedFile != null)
            {
                if (FileUpload2.PostedFile != null)
                {
                    string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                    string FileName1 = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
                    //Save files to disk
                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/upload/" + FileName));
                    FileUpload2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/identification/" + FileName1));

                    String q = "Insert into dbo.requests(request_type,visit_date,reason,request_date,status_id,user_id,user_name,FileName,FilePath,End_vdate,FileName1,FilePath1,RequestNotes,VisitorType)values(N'" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "',N'" + TextBox8.Text + "',N'" + TextBox9.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','4','" + Session["empNo"] + "',N'" + Session["ArbnName"] + "' , @FileName , @FilePath ,N'" + TextBox10.Text + "',@FileName1 , @FilePath1)";
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", FileName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath", "/upload/" + FileName);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName1", FileName1);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FilePath1", "/identification/" + FileName1);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }
            }

            else
            {
                String q = "Insert into dbo.requests(request_type,visit_date,reason,request_date,status_id,user_id,user_name,End_vdate,phone_ext)values(N'" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "',N'" + TextBox8.Text + "',N'" + TextBox9.Text + "','" + DateTime.Now + "','4','" + Session["empNo"] + "' ,N'" + Session["ArbnName"] + "',N'" + TextBox10.Text + "','" + TextBox11.Text.ToString() + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            response.redirect("Personalinformation.aspx");

        }
        else
        {

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Scripts", "<script>alert(' هناك حقول مطلوبة فارغة  ');</script>");

        }
            String c = "Insert into dbo.logFile(user_id,transaction_date,action_type) values ('" + Session["empNo"] + "', '" + DateTime.Now + "' ,N' طلب قبول زائر') ";
            SqlCommand cmdc = new SqlCommand(c, con);
            cmdc.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();


        }
}
   protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("Default.aspx");
}

protected void DropDownList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0) //index of long visit
    {
        FileUpload1.Visible = false;
        FileUpload2.Visible = false;

        Button6.Visible = false;
        TextBox10.Visible = false;
        Label2.Visible = false;
        Label3.Visible = false;

    }

    else
    {
        FileUpload1.Visible = true;
        FileUpload2.Visible = true;
        Button6.Visible = true;
        TextBox10.Visible = true;
        Label2.Visible = true;
        Label3.Visible = true;


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used FileUpload1.SaveAs:

```
       FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/upload/" + FileName));
       FileUpload2.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/identification/" + FileName1));
```

Instead of that use this:

```
       FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/upload/" + FileName));
       FileUpload2.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("/identification/" + FileName1));
```

You are missing PostedFile keyword in that.

Comment: NO when I remove the response redirect it save the file not the path only  ,I try it with an image and I retrieve the image in other page and it's works

Comment: Did you check whether FileUpload1.PostedFile has posted file or not? I think it will be going to else block.

Comment: no because every things in the same insert line is inserted except the file upload

Comment: I have updated my answer. If it solves your problem then please mark it as answer.

Comment: Did you try adding PostedFile keyword at the places I have shown, also did you try to debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Response.Redirect, you can try using Server.Transfer if you intend to transfer the user to other page.

See more details at [difference between Server.Transfer and Response.Redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224569/server-transfer-vs-response-redirect)